# Read from Node fs read stream n number of lines at a time

Tags: node.js

I want to keep the `fs` read stream open and read n number of lines at a time whenever I want manually. I don't want to hook up the on() event handler with 'data' as it makes the stream to continuously read automatically until the end. There is no telling how long it would take before it's manually triggered to read the next set of lines are read.

Comment: Do you need to resume the reading? The native [readline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/readline.html) module could be helpful. What is your input data?

Comment: Yes I have to resume the reading and when I resume is totally unpredictable and can take a long time. Does the native `readline` have a way for me to read `x number of lines` discretely rather than the `pause()` and `resume()` functions that can be unpredictable number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a short function which should do what you want

```
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
// wrapping everything in async function so await can be used
// not needed when global await is available
(async () => {
  // create readable stream
  const stream = createReadStream('lorem.txt', { encoding: 'utf-8' })

  // get readLine function instance
  const { readLine } = await createReader(stream)

  // read 100 lines, you can read as many as you want
  // don't have to read all at once
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    console.log(readLine())
  }

  // readLine factory
  async function createReader(stream) {
    // current bytes
    let bytes = ''

    // await for stream to load and be readable
    await new Promise(r => stream.once('readable', r))

    // return readLine function
    return {
      readLine() {
        let index
        // while there is no new line symbol in current bytes
        while ((index = bytes.indexOf('\n')) === -1) {
          // read some data from stream
          const data = stream.read()
          // if data is null it means that the file ended
          if (data === null) {
            // if no bytes left just return null
            if (!bytes) return null
            // if there are some bytes left return them and clear bytes
            const rest = bytes
            bytes = ''
            return rest
          }
          bytes += data
        }
        // get characters till new line
        const line = bytes.slice(0, index)
        // remove first line from current bytes
        bytes = bytes.slice(index + 1)
        // return the first line
        return line
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for because calling the closure `readLine()` basically reads entire CSV file. I want to be able to read one line and then resume to read another line after an arbitrary amount of time when I manually invoke to read the subsequent line.

Comment: Your csv file must be very short then

Comment: You have to read some data first to determine where the new line symbol is. This is what this code does. But `readLine` returns just one line at a time. You can specify how much data to load in each batch with `stream.read(number)`

Comment: Yes your code works. I completely missed the for loop you added there with reading 100 lines and was surprised to see entire file loaded all at once.

Comment: Seeing as how `readLine()` function is synchronous, would this function cause a problem if a line happens to be really long? Not sure if there is async version of `stream.read()` and if so, would it be worth using it?

Comment: I tested it now with lines longer than one million characters and there was a slight delay, of around 50 ms. I had to change `highWaterMark` like this `const stream = createReadStream('lorem.txt', { encoding: 'utf-8', highWaterMark: 1024 ** 3 })`. This function isn't perfect and it could better handle `null` values because I fill like I did it wrong. I don't about asynchronous version of `stream.read` sadly.

Comment: Thanks for doing that experiment. That sounds like a micro-optimization to me. I'll use it as it is. Thank you very much again.